# Finding the best string match with R

Tags: r, string, string-matching, fuzzy-search

Starting with this `L Hernandez`

From a vector containing the following:

```
[1] "HernandezOlaf "    "HernandezLuciano " "HernandezAdrian "
```

I tried this:

```
'subset(ABC, str_detect(ABC, "L Hernandez") == TRUE)'
```

The name Hernandez which includes the capital L anyplace is the desired output.

The desired output is `HernandezLuciano`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
vec1 <- c("L Hernandez", "HernandezOlaf ","HernandezLuciano ", "HernandezAdrian ")
grep("L ?Hernandez|Hernandez ?L",vec1,value=T)
#[1] "L Hernandez" "HernandezLuciano "
```

#### Update

```
variable <- "L Hernandez"

v1 <- gsub(" ", " ?", variable) #replace space with a space and question mark 
v2 <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]+) ([[:alpha:]]+)", "\\2 ?\\1", variable) #reverse the order of words in the string and add question mark
```

You can also use `strsplit` to split `variable` as @rawr commented

```
grep(paste(v1,v2, sep="|"), vec1,value=T)
#[1] "L Hernandez"       "HernandezLuciano "
```

Comment: It works but I am starting with this. 

    vec1 <- c("HernandezOlaf ","HernandezLuciano ", "HernandezAdrian ")

    variable <- "L Hernandez" 

I would need to programatically get to     "L ?Hernandez|Hernandez ?L"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `agrep` function for approximate string matching.
If you simply run this function it matches every string...

```
agrep("L Hernandez", c("HernandezOlaf ",    "HernandezLuciano ", "HernandezAdrian "))
[1] 1 2 3
```

but if you modify this a little "L Hernandez" -> "Hernandez L"

```
agrep("Hernandez L", c("HernandezOlaf ",    "HernandezLuciano ", "HernandezAdrian "))
[1] 1 2 3
```

and change the max distance

```
agrep("Hernandez L", c("HernandezOlaf ",    "HernandezLuciano ", "HernandezAdrian "),0.01)
[1] 2
```

you get the right answer. This is only an idea, it **might** work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the following if you only want full names after a capital L:

```
vec1[grepl("Hernandez", vec1) & grepl("L\\.*", vec1)]
[1] "L Hernandez"       "HernandezLuciano
```

or

```
vec1[grepl("Hernandez", vec1) & grepl("L[[:alpha:]]", vec1)]
[1] "HernandezLuciano "
```

The expression looks for a match on "Hernandez" and then looks to see if there is a capital "L" followed by any character or space.  The second version requires a letter after the capital "L".

BTW, it appears that you can't chain the grepls.

```
vec1[grepl("Hernandez", vec1) & grepl("L\\[[:alpha:]]", vec1)]
character(0)
```